# Display custom categories in custom post loop

Tags: wordpress

I am learning to create a Portfolio section. I already created the custom post type and a custom taxonomy for the portfolio categories. The categories are working ok, i can choose which category i want for every portfolio item.

I am trying to loop within the post_type portfolio to get the items and it works ok, but i cannot get the categories of each item.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio') ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="panel">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I am using the above code, but the categories dont show up.

I tried separately to display the categories and are working ok with this code:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories', );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php echo $category->name;?>
    <?php } 
?>
```

So how can i display each portfolio item categories in the loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code, this will print all custom taxonomies of post.

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_categories' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

    $taxonomies = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $taxonomies[] = $term->name;
    }

    $taxonomies = implode(", ", $taxonomies );
    ?>

    <p class="Custom-Taxonomies">
        Custom Taxonomies: <span><?php echo $taxonomies; ?> </span>
    </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```